# Full Screen Doesn't Work on IE8 in mediaelement.js

Tags: mediaelement.js

When looking at a video in MediaElement.js on IE8. Clicking on Full screen button doesn't make the video full screen. (Tried this on mediaelementjs.com as well). But clicking on the caption "Full Screen" works. Is this a code out of location?

Answer (score 0):

One alternative solution is to use a Windows Media Player `<object>` instead of HTML `<video>` if the browser is IE, and use the `<video>` for other browsers.

(For Windows Media Player with id Player, you can access Fullscreen by `Player.Fullscreen='True'` Please double check this before using)